# Integral of $\sqrt{c-\cos(x)}$ where c is a constant

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

I am having trouble calculating the following integral:

$$ {\int \sqrt{c-\cos(t)} dt}  $$

where $c$ is a constant.

In the very specific case where $c=1$, it is rather easy, but I cannot seem to be able to generalize that.

I tried running it with Wolfram but it produces higher-than-my-paygrade math ([example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%284+-+cos%28psi%29%29)) about elliptic integrals and I can't help but think it should be easier than that.

Comment: "I can't help but think it should be easier than that" -- what makes you think that?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg the fact that the $c=1$ case is so simple and the simplicity of the function to be integrated itself. It just does not seem as if it would suddenly become unstable left and right of the $c=1$ point. I am obviously mistaken, but..

Comment: That's because for $\color{blue}{c = 1}$, you can use the half-angle identity $\sin^2(x) = \dfrac{\color{blue}{1}-\cos(2x)}{2}$.

Comment: @KM101 I just had this notion that the integral of *smooth* functions produce *smooth* results. I might have to rethink that.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: the elliptic integrals *are* smooth functions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust So I guess the $c=1$ case also turns into a elliptic integral; it is just a special one, right?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: indeed, there is no reason to exclude $c=1$ from the general case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not easier than that. Wolfram showing you "weird" functions is a sure sign, if not a proof*.

The elliptic integrals have become very classical. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

It is easy to understand why the case of $c=1$ is simpler. In the plots you see that the blue curve *is* a (rectified) sinusoid, while the others are not, as can be checked analytically.

[image]

---

*A proof is possible but highly technical, based on Liouville's theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)

---

Also note that a simple integrand rarely means a simple antiderivative. Try `integrate 1/(x^5+1)`.

Comment: Suggestion: One could derive the general formula for the integral in terms of an elliptic integral (or something else, power series?) as in nmasanta's answer for $c \neq 1$, and then show how if the parameter $c \to 1$, that formula converges to the seemingly easier elementary integral the OP knows for that one. (I.e. fitting the case $c=1$ "smoothly" into the general one.) That would make this great answer perfect in my view.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: there seems to be undue and unnecessary focusing on the fact that $c=1$ is a "special case". In the frame of the elliptic integrals, this makes little sense, this is just a value of the parameter like another. And there is no such concept as "continuity in having an elementary expression".

Comment: The expression in nmasanta's answer contains the term $c-1$ in a denominator, so if it is correct, one cannot just set the parameter $c=1$ in the general solution with elliptic integrals, and I would just be interested to see how the $\lim_{c\to1}$ of that expression exists and becomes the elementary function the OP noticed for that case. -- Nowhere did or would I claim what you put in quotes in your last sentence, did I phrase something unclearly there?

Answer (score 3):

For the specific case where $~=1~$, this integral is rather easy because here you can use a trigonometric formula $~1-\cos t~=~2\sin^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)~$ directly in the second line and got a known trigonometric function $\big($here it is $\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\big)$ which can be integrable by known formula (as we have the knowledge that anti-derivative of $~\cos t~$ is $~\sin t~+~c$, where $c$ is a constant) . But for the value $~c=2~$or more you can't find such form.

**For example**, if you take $~c=2~$, you  got (after some steps) a function  as $~\sqrt{2\sin^2\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right)+1}~$. There is no elementary function whose derivative is $~\sqrt{2\sin^2\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right)+1}~$. Here you have to allow yourself to know about a special integral called **[incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind)**.

- Here is the complete solution of the given integral.

\begin{equation}
I={\displaystyle\int}\sqrt{c-\cos\left(t\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
={\displaystyle\int}\sqrt{c-1}\cdot\sqrt{\dfrac{2\sin^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{c-1}+1}\,~\mathrm{d}t\\
\end{equation}
Substituting $~u=\dfrac{t}{2}~$, so $~\mathrm{d}t=2\,\mathrm{d}u~$. Now
\begin{equation}
 I=\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{2\sqrt{c-1}}}{\cdot}{\displaystyle\int}\sqrt{\dfrac{2\sin^2\left(u\right)}{c-1}+1}\,~\mathrm{d}u\tag1
\end{equation}

> We know that 
>   \begin{equation}
> {\displaystyle\int}\sqrt{\dfrac{2\sin^2\left(u\right)}{c-1}+1}\,\mathrm{d}u~~
> =~~\operatorname{E}\left(u\,\middle|\,-\dfrac{2}{c-1}\right)
> \end{equation}
>   This is a special integral ([incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind)).

Hence from $(1)$ ,
\begin{equation}
 I~=~2\sqrt{c-1}~\operatorname{E}\left(u\,\middle|\,-\dfrac{2}{c-1}\right)~+~K\\
=2\sqrt{c-1}\operatorname{E}\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\,\middle|\,-\dfrac{2}{c-1}\right)~+~K
\end{equation}
where $~K~$ is constant and $~c\ne 1~$.

For $~c=1~$, the value of the integral is $$~I~=~-2^\frac{3}{2}\cos\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right)+K~$$

Comment: The OP is asking for a simpler solution, he already knows that given by Alpha.

Comment: You just didn't get that you have to tell the OP there isn't one. This is his question. There is little added value in your answer compared to Alpha.

Comment: I think now the answer is okay @Yves Daoust. By the way thanks for your kind attention. It really help me to improve my thoughts.

Comment: "There is no known function whose derivative is $~\sqrt{2\sin^2\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right)+1}~$". Wrong, of course there is one, and you write it down soon after. It's just that there is (demonstrably) no *elementary* function whose derivative ... . It's important to help the OP to get past the point where they think $-2 \sqrt{1 - \cos(t)} \cot(t/2)$ is a function but $2\sqrt{c-1}E\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\,\middle|\,-\dfrac{2}{c-1}\right)$ is not. The're both well-defined functions. We're just more used to the first one from high school and our pocket calculators.

Comment: @nmasanta the general answer that you reach does not hold for $c=1$ though. Looking at it like that, there is a kind of *singularity* for the $c=1$ case which makes it *easily* solvable.

Comment: Yes @Ev.Kounis there is a removable singularity at $c=1$.

Comment: A plot of the $I(c, t)$ would go a long way in assisting understanding if you can generate one

Answer (score 0):

$$=\int{\sqrt {c -1}\sqrt{\frac{2sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{c-1}+1dt}}$$
substitute $u=\frac{t}{2}$ -> $\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}$ -> $dt = 2du$
$$= 2\sqrt{c-1}.\int \sqrt{\frac{2sin^2u}{c-1}+1}du$$
If you solve this integral you will find the solution as
$$2\sqrt{c-1}E(\frac{x}{2}|-\frac{2}{c-1})+C$$

Comment: If you don't say what $E$ stands for, this answer is useless. Not counting that the OP already knew this from Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I am so sorry for I didn't guess that you don't know the Elliptic integral :(

Comment: Don't be ironic, I know them very well. The OP does not. Also ponder that $E$ might not be a standard notation.